# Cplex C++ add variable column wise (cutstock)

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I'm trying to solve the cutting stock problem using column generation. Cplex (c++) has a good example, where each pattern fills one piece of stock. I'm trying to expand that so that more than one pattern can fill a piece of stock.

[Latex for what I'm going for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd3LH.png)

[Latex for what I've got now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1WQO.png)

The relevant piece of code in the example is the following column expression:

```
IloModel masterPr(env);

    IloObjective   SheetsUsed = IloAdd(masterPr, IloMinimize(env));
    IloRangeArray  demandArray = IloAdd(masterPr,
        IloRangeArray(env, demand, IloInfinity));
    IloNumVarArray Patterns(env);

//GENERATE pattern SOMEHOW

  Patterns.add(IloNumVar(SheetsUsed(1) + demandArray(pattern));
```

where Patterns are all the columns represting a pattern using a full "Sheet". Demand array is the demand matrix, with pattern representing how many of each item is in this pattern. How can I go about making the new variable x column wise, so I can fit more than one pattern on a sheet?

Comment: One option is to use a generic [Dantzig–Wolfe decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig-Wolfe_decomposition), there are few examples of how to do it with [cplex](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399997), in particular [with C](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399997&aid=5). Another option is to transform your input data to make the problem look like the problem from cplex example, e.g., x_{new} <-- (x, y).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is that you need to understand how columnwise modeling works in ILOG Concert C++ for CPLEX.  In the example you gave, the statement

```
Patterns.add(IloNumVar(SheetsUsed(1) + demandArray(pattern));
```

is adding a decision variable that will have an objective function coefficient of 1, and that variable will appear in the constraint called `demandArray[i]` with a coefficient equal to the value of `pattern[i]`. What you will need to do is for each pattern, do a few things:

1. Add multiple decision variables (the `x` in your LaTeX formulation) to correspond to the sheets.
2. When you add a decision variable to the `x` array, it will have nonzeros in some additional constraints that you will need to create, similar to how `demandArray` is created.
3. When you add a sheet, you will have to add one variable to your `Patterns` variable, corresponding to your `y` in LaTeX.

This is not easy to do, mostly because all of us are so used to row-wise modeling as opposed to column-wise modeling.